# Displaying JSON data on condition using V-for and V-if in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, vue.js

I am fetching data(Orders) from external Api in Vue using axios. I obtain JSON data and i am able to show it in a HTML table. Now i am trying filter the data to show only related data to use. In my Json data, i have a field called "order status: Completed / processing". Now i only want to show the json data which are have status like "Processing" to achieve my goal.

I am trying to use v-if with v-for but I m unable to get the certain orders data and view.

The table is set to update for each minute.

Here is my code:

html code

```
**<div class ="container mt-4" id="app">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
               
                <th scope="col">Order id</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Items</th>
                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                <th scope="col">Print</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr
              v-for="(order, index) in orders" v-if="order.status === "processing""
              :key="order.id"
              :class="{highlight: !order.is_printed}"
              > 
                    <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.first_name + " " +order.billing.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.date_created }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.address_1 + ", " + order.billing.address_2 + ", " + order.billing.city + order.billing.postcode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.line_items[0].name}} </td>
                    <td>{{ order.total}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="printBill(order)">Print</button>
                     
                  </tr>
            </tbody>            
          </table>**
```

Vue

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      orders: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
  // API Call function to be implemented here....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to filter data after you get them from api.
based on vue.js document it’s not recommended to use v-if and v-for together, read this:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

try this

```
let filteredData = this.orders.filter(order => order.status === "processing")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

According to Vue documentation it's best to put any logic into computed properties https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    orders: [
      { id: 1, status: "processing"},
      { id: 2, status: "other" }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredOrders() {
            return this.orders.filter(order => order.status === 'processing');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="order in filteredOrders" :key="order.id">
          <td>{{ order.status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```